# will an aws step workflow work with an infinite loop?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am considering using step functions to poll every 30 seconds for updates from an external db and run a mapping lambda that will store the data in s3.

Implementing the step functions is straightforward enough.  I have noticed the limits are set to run for 1 year. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html

the question i have is will this work or is there a flaw in using step functions for this purpose.   the price of 0.025 per 1000 steps is acceptable for my scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The size of the execution history of a step function execution is limited to [25,000 events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-state-machine-executions). Each Lambda task takes 5 events. So you can only have 500 states execution in a single execution of state machine.

In your case, the execution of state machine will fail after 30*5000 seconds ( ~4 hours). You may need to start a new execution every 4 hrs to make sure your DB sync works.

How to mitigate this?

[AWS Step Functions history event limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882749/aws-step-functions-history-event-limitation/49244133#49244133)

Note: Though this question is old, I am answering this for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: thank you for the answer.  the limitations that you point out is new information to myself

Answer (score 1):

This workflow should work pretty well - since the state machine can last up to a year, it's almost like AWS encourages this type of work load.

On a side note, I was actually surprised at how low a cost this would actually be: $75 for 3 state transitions running all year.

- Roughly 500,000 minutes per year (figure 1 million if every 30 seconds)
- $0.000025 per state transition
- (1,000,000 * 3) * $0.000025 = **$75**

Comment: It actually crazy expensive you can achieve the same thing using lambda with a scheduled execution will save 750$

Comment: I accidentally added an extra zero - the price should be only $75 a year. Invoking a Lambda function 3 million times would cost less than $1.00. So still significantly more price wise. It still might be worth the price being able to break out functions into steps. Good callout though!